# TwinCAT - How to measure program execution time?

Tags: plc, twincat

I would like to measure the execution time of a structured text (ST) program. The task associated with the program is running at 10 ms.

How do I measure execution time?

Comment: Currently not very useful, but Beckhoff will introduce a Profiler product sometime in the future. I think it will come with 4026. It enables you to add a Profiler project to a PLC project. The Profiler will then show you execution times down to individual functions/function blocks.

Comment: Profiler was mentioned in the [2021 Automation update presentation](https://github.com/Roald87/TwinCatChangelog/files/6746267/___Beckhoff_automation-update-2021-twincat-e.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use free TwinCAT library `Tc2_Utilities` that has a function block `Profiler`.

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35053195.html&id=1344160655692967299

*The "Profiler" function block can be used to allow the execution time of PLC code to be measured.*

The Infosys page has an example code also:

```
VAR
    Profiler1     : PROFILER;
END_VAR


Profiler1(START := TRUE, RESET := TRUE);

//Do something here

Profiler1(START := FALSE);
//Now Profiler1.Data has the execution time
```

Comment: My build is 4024. I don't think it has profiler option. I used LTIME to get difference in ns.

Comment: The Profiler function block has been available since TwinCAT 2

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use Profiler but just for demonstration purpose you can measure execution time like this.

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
    VAR
        tStart: TIME; (* Time program start *)
        tWork : TIME; (* Execution time *)
    END_VAR

    (* First line of main program *)
    tStart := TIME();

    // Your program here

    (* Last line of your program *)
    tWork := TIME() - tStart;
END_PROGRAM
```

Comment: This was my first thought. However my time difference is in ns and TIME() couldn't do measurement in that range.

Comment: Even with LTIME, which measures nano seconds, this doesn't seem to work. I think the TIME() and LTIME() functions return a value that is only updated once a frame.